# Why C# console app with one line of code (throw new Exception()) spawns child process with the same name just before being terminated?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, process

I was testing my C# console app today (ConsoleApp1), and ran *pslist* (Sysinternal tool) in terminal mode (`pslist -s ConsoleApp1`) to observe if only one instance is created. All was working ok, so I started to make some changes in code, and ended with an unhandled exception. When it was raised, I noticed that pslist showed 2 instances of a process with ConsoleApp1 name, and different PIDs. Out of curiosity, I did a minimal reproduction, and it looks like just throwing an exception in Main causes the new process to appear.

I was not able to see this second process in Task Manager, even in Administrative mode. I was only able to see it in pslist and in another console app, which was executing `Process.GetProcessesByName` in a loop. Parent process of the first one is explorer.exe (expected), while parent of the second one is the first process. Second one has the same MainModule (i.e. originates from the same executable), but its Main method is never executed.

Could anyone enlighten me what the second process is and why Task Manager doesn't display it?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create new Console app (tried in .NET 4.8 and .NET 6)
2. Replace content of Main with `throw new Exception();`
3. Compile the code (no matter if this is Debug or Release)
4. Run `pslist -s ConsoleApp1` in a separate cmd window. Change the name if you used different one.
5. Run app by double clicking it in File Explorer and observe pslist window - both processes should be displayed for a second.

Comment: See if this helps : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/about-exceptions-and-capturing-them-with-dumps/ba-p/2234600#:~:text=When%20a%20process%20is%20started%2C%20Windows%20creates%20associated,taken%20in%20the%20attempt%20for%20recovery%3A%20First%20chance

Comment: @jdweng if you mean I could take a memory dump and analyze it, then I have to admit that I'm not sure this would answer any of my questions. I guess it _might_, although I have no idea how, but I'm not really prepared to jump into such analysis at the moment. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: @jdweng I took a look at the linked article again, and this time I wonder if you thought about the whole "how exceptions are handled" paragraph. If so, it might be the part of the answer, but I'd really like to know what exactly is going on, and why is the child process created.